# Execute file in ipython interpreter

Tags: python, file, interpreter, ipython

I'm trying to run a file inside the ipython interpreter. 
The documentation makes this sound as simple as `ipython file.py` in the shell or `%run file.py` inside the interpreter itself. However, I want to read a file that contains commands to the ipython "system shell". Here's an example:

```
files= !ls
print files
```

for this type of commands, invoking the interpreter as mentioned above results in SyntaxError, as if it was executed by `/usr/bin/python`.

Is it possible to run a file **from the system shell** as if it were executing inside the ipython shell interpreter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can do this if you name your file with an .ipy extension.

```
sam@blackbird-debian:~
$ cat tmp.ipy
me = !whoami
print me
sam@blackbird-debian:~
$ ipython tmp.ipy
['sam']
```

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to do this from an already running IPython session. There is probably something **much** simpler, but all I could think of right now is:

```
get_ipython().shell.run_cell(open('path/to/commands').read())
```

Another crazy idea - start IPython as `EDITOR=cat ipython`. Now you can load commands from a file with:

```
%edit -r path/to/commands
```

There should probably be a real magic for your use case, though.

---

Or you could do the same thing non-interactively (add `-i` to drop into interactive mode):

```
ipython -c 'get_ipython().shell.run_cell(open("path/to/commands").read())'
```

Comment: Hoa, that second one is creative. I'm trying to run a file from the command line though, I guess I was not clear on that (I'll edit)

Comment: I had to leave off the `.shell` in your first example.  After that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, it may be sufficient to run

```
ipython < file
```

from bash. That is, just redirect standard input to ipython from your file, so that ipython thinks the commands it's getting are coming from your keyboard.

Comment: Won't this keep executing blindly after a exception is thrown, for example?